# LINQ to delete a collection from master collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 collections:

```
List<masterDataCollection> master = client.GetAllMasterData().ToList();
List<selectedDataCollection> selected = client.GetAllSelectedData.ToList();
```

How do I deleted the selected list from the master list using LINQ? Is there a quick way of doing it?

Comment: What means "delete", do you want to delete them from the collection or from the database? How are the two types related at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case both types have id fields and all ids in selected list exists in master list:

```
selected.ForEach(q => master.Remove(master.Single(l => l.Id == q.Id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is usually to use the RemoveAll() method.
Since you with to remove based on ID you could do the following;

```
var selectedIds = selected.Select(x => x.Id).ToList<Int>(); //Given that they are integers.
master.RemoveAll(x => selectedIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

Comment: They seem to be two different types, but even if they are compatible they need to override `Equals` to not only compare references.

Comment: I can´t see how this could work out of the box like that since master & selected do not contain the same type.

Comment: Yes they are 2 different types. I want to delete based on ID which is common in both. How do I do that?

Comment: Please see edit, this is simply an idea of how you would be able to achieve this.